# Getting UTF string from perl's subprocess

Tags: perl, utf-8

I am working on a simple script that gets and sets background in Ubuntu Linux ( version 16.04 , but that's irrelevant in this case ). The problem is that my folder names are UTF-8 encoded ( Chinese, specifically). Thus, getting path to current wallpaper fails , like so:

```
my $user_background=qx/gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri/;
```

Output of `print $user_background`:

```
file:///home/xieerqi/%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD/testimage.jpg
```

Thus, the question is: **how do I get properly encoded/decoded string from a shell command in perl**

I did try this:

```
my $unicode_String=Encode::decode('utf-8', $user_background );
```

which didn't work.

Adding `binmode(STDOUT,":utf8");` also didn't help

Adding `use utf8;` didn't work

Strangely, using that same string to set background does work.

Comment: `%E4%B8%8B` is **URL-encoded** because you asked for a URL. The characters making up the URL are already plain 7-bit ASCII, so you aren't getting anything when you decode with UTF-8. Since you wanted a URL, you got a URL - if you want a proper path, you'll have to URL-decode it first, then apply UTF-8 decoding.

Comment: @mneonneo OK , so how do I  URL-decode ? because if you do `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.background` you'll see there is only one key, `picture-uri`, there is no option to decode it

Comment: So far I see a lot of hints that this is URL-encoded. OK , I get that. But what is the way to decode that URL ? Simply telling me  "go fish" without showing how doesn't seem like a proper answer

Comment: I'm not a Perl expert, but you could use something like the URL package (http://search.cpan.org/~rse/lcwa-1.0.0/lib/lwp/lib/URI/URL.pm) to parse the URL and extract the unescaped path component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to extract the path from the URL.

```
use open ':std', ':locale';
use feature qw( say );

use Encode      qw( decode_utf8 );
use URI         qw( );
use URI::Escape qw( uri_unescape );

my $url = URI->new('file:///home/xieerqi/%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD/testimage.jpg');

$url->scheme eq 'file'
   or die("Invalid input\n");

my $path = decode_utf8( uri_unescape( $url->path ) );

say $path;
```

As a one-liner:

```
perl -CS -MEncode=decode_utf8 -MURI -MURI::Escape=uri_unescape \
   -e'CORE::say( decode_utf8( uri_unescape( URI->new($ARGV[0])->path ) ) )' \
      file:///home/xieerqi/%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD/testimage.jpg
```

Since the previous snippet assumes a UTF-8 terminal, we might as well avoid the decoding and the encoding that follows it practically immediately:

```
perl -MURI -MURI::Escape=uri_unescape \
   -e'CORE::say( uri_unescape( URI->new($ARGV[0])->path ) )' \
      file:///home/xieerqi/%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD/testimage.jpg
```

Answer (score 4):

That looks correct to me. The characters have been UTF-8 encoded and then URL encoded, so the URL should identify the file correctly. You shouldn't expect to be able to read it

The string `%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD` corresponds to

```
- `E4 B8 8B`, which is the character U+4E0B or 下

- `E8 BD BD`, which is the character U+8F7D or 载
```

下载 is "download". Is that right?

What do you actually want to do with the string? You may get something readable if you use `picture-filename` instead of `picture-uri`

Comment: Yes, that is correct string. I was trying to print out the output of `gsettings`. Turns out that gsettings outputs non-decoded strings for some odd reason. See my post

Comment: `picture-filename` won't work, gsettings schema only has `picture-uri` key. That's not up to me

Comment: @Serg: You asked for a URI so it had no choice but to URL-encode the UTF-8. Anything else wouldn't be a valid URI.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the issue was with `gsettings` itself. Even on command-line, it returns the same string with chinese characters not decoded.

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri                                                                 
'file:///home/xieerqi/%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD/ad32d5d0615e9572-121171d86d0c8618-e11082638606a82c303fee0b29697811.jpg'
```

Even if forcing environment, it returns the same string

```
$ LC_ALL=C gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri                                                        
'file:///home/xieerqi/%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD/ad32d5d0615e9572-121171d86d0c8618-e11082638606a82c303fee0b29697811.jpg'
```

However, it seems that the proper way with subprocess output that goes to a scalar , is to use `decode_utf8()` method. Basically,here's what I tried, and successfully got output

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Encode;
my $stuff=qx/ls ~ /;
my $utf_string = decode_utf8( $stuff );
print "$utf_string";
```

Comment: As others have already explained, the issue isn't that gsettings is broken like you seem to be suggesting, it's that you asked it to give you a URI, which means you get a URI-encoded string.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that `gsettings` is broken.  I merely said it returns what appears to be non-decoded string. OK, how can i decode URI ?  can you point me to a tutorial or another SO post ?